# How to re-arrange string lines in python

Tags: python, stringio

I have string like below mentioned and contain n number of lines per group  and I would like to arrange the string as mentioned below ..

```
real   51.85ms
sys    22.41ms
usr    29.70ms
[www.ms786.com] 2345 sunset follow
Multidd    567890KB

real   61.85ms
sys    32.41ms
usr    27.70ms
[www.ms586.com] 4345 sunset follow
Multidd    4567890KB

real   51.85ms
sys    12.41ms
usr    41.70ms
[www.ms186.com] 7345 sunset follow
Multidd    8967890KB
```

TO

```
[www.ms786.com] 2345 sunset follow
Multidd    567890KB
real   51.85ms
sys    22.41ms
usr    29.70ms
Multidd    567890KB

[www.ms586.com] 4345 sunset follow
Multidd    4567890KB
real   61.85ms
sys    32.41ms
usr    27.70ms

[www.ms186.com] 7345 sunset follow
Multidd    8967890KB
real   51.85ms
sys    12.41ms
usr    41.70ms`
```

Could you help how it can be reshuffled in the string itself. Will really appreciate your help

Comment: So for each four lines (group), the forth line should instead be the first, is that it?

Comment: Yes Sam. You got correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works by defining how lines for each block should be arranged. For example with `"340125"` old line 3 will become new line 0, old line 4 -> new line 1, and so on.
It will work with all block structures up to 10 lines per block, as long as the structure stays the same for all blocks.

```
class BlockRearrange:
    def __init__(self, order):
        self.order = list(map(int, order))
        self.blocksize = len(self.order)
    
    def reorder(self, s):
        result = ""
        lines = s.splitlines()

        for block_pos in range(0, len(lines), self.blocksize):
            part = lines[block_pos:block_pos+self.blocksize]
            part_length = len(part)

            for n in self.order:
                if n < part_length:
                    result += part[n] + "\n"
        
            if part_length < self.blocksize:
                break

        return result

# Create instance with formula for how to rearrange the blocks.
# The order-string needs to contain every line of the block,
# even those not changing positions.
br = BlockRearrange("340125")

print(br.reorder(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution does this efficiently, by locating group headers and shifting them back to their right positions:

```
s = """real   51.85ms
sys    22.41ms
usr    29.70ms
[www.ms786.com] 2345 sunset follow
Multidd    567890KB

real   61.85ms
sys    32.41ms
usr    27.70ms
[www.ms586.com] 4345 sunset follow
Multidd    4567890KB

real   51.85ms
sys    12.41ms
usr    41.70ms
[www.ms186.com] 7345 sunset follow
Multidd    8967890KB"""

def move_header_back(lines, header_prefix, base_index = 0):
    # Find group header positions
    group_header_positions = [base_index - 1] + [i + 1 for i in range(len(lines)) if lines[i].startswith(header_prefix)]
    # If no group positions found (there is one as we inserted `0` regardless)
    if 1 == len(group_header_positions):
        return lines
    # Shift back groups headers
    for i in range(1, len(group_header_positions)):
        group_header = lines.pop(group_header_positions[i] - 1)
        lines.insert(group_header_positions[i - 1] + 1, group_header)
    return lines

def fix_group_positions(lines):
    move_header_back(lines, header_prefix = '[',        base_index=0)
    move_header_back(lines, header_prefix = 'Multidd',  base_index=1)
    # Join back lines
    return '\n'.join(lines)

lines = [l for l in s.split('\n') if l]
print(fix_group_positions(lines))
```

Output:

```
[www.ms786.com] 2345 sunset follow
Multidd    567890KB
real   51.85ms
sys    22.41ms
usr    29.70ms
[www.ms586.com] 4345 sunset follow
Multidd    4567890KB
real   61.85ms
sys    32.41ms
usr    27.70ms
[www.ms186.com] 7345 sunset follow
Multidd    8967890KB
real   51.85ms
sys    12.41ms
usr    41.70ms
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is really amazing!. I just have one modification ..there is extra line added after the line containing sunset follow for the group. Eg 
real   51.85ms
sys    22.41ms
usr    29.70ms
[www.ms786.com] 2345 sunset follow
Multidd 56789
real   51.85ms
sys    22.41ms
usr    29.70ms
[www.ms586.com] 2345 sunset follow
Multidd 798798798

Comment: Which modification? @Asrar

Comment: @Yaniv I have modified my example with exact pattern

Comment: @Asrar Updated :)

Comment: @Yaniv, Much appreciated. I will be embedding same thing in my code which runs for thousands of servers. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @yaniv HI Yaniv ,  I required further improvement on this that the line starting with multidd should be always 2nd line of the string.

Comment: @Asrar please don't change the requirements periodically. Updated.

Comment: Thank you so much Yaniv  for your helps.. Actually data kept changing I am totally new vibe in Python. I really appreciate your help !